# Unable to install a package, newer libc6 required

Tags: debian, apt

I was trying to install `openvasv6` using instructions given [here](http://www.openvas.org/install-packages-v6.html).

I am using Debian Wheezy (amd64).

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install greenbone-security-assistant openvas-cli openvas-manager openvas-scanner openvas-administrator sqlite3 xsltproc rsync
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
rsync is already the newest version.
sqlite3 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 greenbone-security-assistant : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
                                Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 openvas-administrator : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
                         Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 openvas-cli : Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 openvas-manager : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
 openvas-scanner : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.13-38+deb7u1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libopenvas5 (>= 5.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it possible to fix this problem and install the packages?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list`? The repository mentioned in http://www.openvas.org/install-packages-v6.html#openvas_debian_obs has packages built for Debian 7 wheezy (even for Debian 6 squeeze, I think), but it seems that you're trying to install from a package source built for Debian 8 jessie.

Answer (score 1):

The errors say that the packages you are trying to install depend on newer system packages than those available in the Debian's system repository.

Basically it means these packages require either a newer version of Debian (say testing branch) or a different distribution with newer system packages.

The reason Debian does not have newer system packages in Wheezy is because Debian is all about stability. After a release very few updates are pushed, so that no feature is broken and no new bugs are introduced.

If you really need these packages, you can upgrade your Debian to the [testing version](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting).

Comment: i am using amazon ec2. So do you have anyother solution ?

Comment: @MadTerry No, I can not think of anything else, except using a different distribution (or Debian testing version).